# How expensive is assigning a Dictionary object?

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing

Recently I found a problem with assigning Dictionary object to the custom object property. I have a function that call 400,000 and inside the function try to assign a dictionary object to the one of my custom object's property. When I calculated the time, I found there is about 1500 ms difference:

```
CustomClass[] customObjects = new CustomClass[400000];
for (int indx = 0; indx < 400000; indx++)
{
    customObjects[indx] = new CustomClass
    {
        Prop1 = new Dictionary<long, Class1>{ { 1, new Class1 { Prop1 = 2 , Prop2 = "Some Text 1" , Prop3 = DateTime.Now  } }, 
                                        { 2, new Class1 { Prop1 = 3 , Prop2 = "Some Text 2" , Prop3 = DateTime.Now } } 
        }
    };
}


var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Parallel.For(0, 400000, (indx) =>
{
    var myNewDic = new Dictionary<long, Class1>() { { 1, new Class1 { Prop1 = 2 , Prop2 = "Some Text 1" , Prop3 = DateTime.Now } }, 
                                        { 2, new Class1 { Prop1 = 3, Prop2 = "Some Text 2" , Prop3 = DateTime.Now  } } };

    customObjects[indx].Prop1 = myNewDic; // this one is slower

});

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("First try has been finished with: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
Parallel.For(0, 400000, (indx) =>
{
    var myNewDic = new Dictionary<long, Class1>() { { 1, new Class1 { Prop1 = 2 , Prop2 = "Some Text 1" , Prop3 = DateTime.Now } }, 
                                        { 2, new Class1 { Prop1 = 3, Prop2 = "Some Text 2" , Prop3 = DateTime.Now  } } };

    foreach (var key in myNewDic.Keys) // this one is faster
    {
        customObjects[indx].Prop1[key].Prop1 = myNewDic[key].Prop1;
    }
});

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Second try has been finished with: {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Result:**

**[image: Result:]**

My assumption is assigning dictionary should only change the pointer in memory and Garbage collector should destroy old value, but seems there is something more than this.

Is anyone has a opinion?

Comment: I advise you to use `bool myNewDic.TryGet(key, out value)`, this will check for existence, but also gets the value. This will prevent multiple lookups.

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't get your point, in both we have customObjects[indx]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that reproduces the issue. You're claiming that one assignment is slower than assigning in a loop and assigning another variable.

Comment: Your example code is obscure. if `customObjects` is `CustomClass[]`, then how do you assign a dictionary (`customObjects[indx] = myNewDic;`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry, fixed the code

Comment: Yes @CodeCaster one assigment is slower than the other one

Comment: So, what does the setter of Prop1 do?

Comment: Nothing @CodeCaster, it's simple Setter that's why I get confused

Comment: Again, we can't reproduce this. Create a minimal example that reproduces the issue. The problem may very well lie in how you actually benchmark this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: all I'm describing here are implementation details as far as C# and .NET is concerned, and can change at any time with an updated .NET runtime and/or C# version. This is valid for current Microsoft.NET runtime on Windows. This shouldn't be surprising - we're talking about performance optimizations, after all, and the problem here is caused by a non-optimal garbage collection and memory allocation mechanisms, which may be improved in the future :)

The main reason between your two examples is where the dictionary that "dies" is allocated. Since you're dealing with 400 000 items, it's pretty safe to assume that the dictionaries in your `customObjects` array are already in Gen 2 heap, and somewhere in the middle of other allocated objects. On the other hand, your newly created dictionary doesn't survive a single loop iteraton, and will most likely be allocated in Gen 0 heap.

This has two main effects:

- Gen 0 heaps are smaller, faster to traverse and collect. As long as you don't allocate enough persistent memory to cross a threshold, all your allocations and collections are going to dealing with Gen 0, which is a lot faster. This still isn't as cheap as stack collection, but it comes quite close in your usual application.
- When you collect a bit of memory from the middle of a heap, every single object above it needs to be moved so that there's no "free space" in the heap. This is because apart from LoH, .NET heap allocations are always done from the top of the heap, the same as with the stack. This makes allocations very fast, but it means that heap must be compacted when memory is freed to make sure the free memory is actually useable. Needless to say, moving half the heap is quite expensive if your heap is large.

Your sample doesn't actually produce a meaningful difference on my machine - this is most likely due to the fact that it only allocates a relatively small amount of memory, which fits the whole heap nicely into processor cache. More memory to move means more work.

Basically, your approach kills the generational garbage collector by using pretty much the worst allocation strategy possible - replacing a long lived object with a short lived object, which will consequently be promoted to higher generations until it's again replaced by a short lived object. Your problem isn't the assignment (unless there's some code you're hiding from us :)), it's the fact that you have to collect the old dictionary.

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I tried running your latest sample through a profiler. Under the profiler, the fast version takes about 8.5s, the slow version around 9.5s. This is not surprising - a full allocation/call profiling takes quite a bit of work, and tends to remove or hide some other sources of contention.

So, what do we see from the memory profiling?

- The lifetime of objects in the slow version is more or less spread throughout the whole application. In the fast version, only single digits of objects that don't survive the whole run survive more than one collection.
- In both versions, almost all objects that are alive in the end are in Gen 1/2 (the two heaps aren't easy to distinguish, but it's not very important for our purposes). This is mainly because the Gen 0 heap is severely size limited.
- In the slow version, almost all of the heap memory (234 MB out of 246 MB total) has been relocated. In the fast version, just a few kilobytes were relocated. This is a big deal - it means that the slow version compacted the heap like crazy, while the fast version pretty much didn't have to do any compaction at all. In the slow version, this involved moving a total of about four million objects - in the fast version, six *hundred*. This includes moving each of the `Class1` objects almost four times on average.
- The slow version did 8 Gen 0 heap collections, while the fast version did 22. This is a huge difference - it shows how much better the fast version suits the generational GC. And while the slow version did 3 Gen 2, only one more than the fast's 2 collections, we've already seen that the fast version's Gen 2 collections were almost trivial compared to the slow version. The first two Gen 2 collections involve no collections, in fact - they both occur during the setup phase, simply as a side-effect of all the allocations we're doing.
- The difference between the two versions is much smaller in the single-threaded version. Again, this is unsurprising - after removing the `DateTime.Now` (which otherwise takes 80-90% of CPU time, which is impractical for our test), the workload is heavily dominated by the GC. And when the GC runs, none of the other threads do - since GC takes much less time in the fast version, the parallel version is all the faster. In my tests without profiling, the non-parallel version has the fast about half the time of the slow, while the parallel version makes the fast almost five times as fast as the slow (on my four core machine).

Running just a simple concurrency profiling usually gives the slow version about twice as slow as the fast version, and you can easily see that the GC is to blame - the difference between the two versions is easily seen with the naked eye. In the slow version, the GC freezes all threads ten times or so, and there's very little time left for any work to be done. In the fast version, there's only *one* such freeze (your results might vary, of course), and the total blocking time is around 5%.

The takeaway from all this is: make sure that your long-living objects live long, and your short-lived objects die as soon as possible. The worst thing you can do is periodically replace (logically) long-lived objects with newly created objects.

Comment: Thanks @Luaan for your answer, there is no hidden code, just cannot write the real code here coz there are too many dependencies. So just I wrote sample code and post it here. I updated my code with result. You can see the difference between each block.

Comment: @Peyman Added profiling data. It seems to support my conclusions, but see for yourself :)

Comment: Thanks @Luaan, now it makes sense for me

Answer (score 0):

That line: `customObjects[indx].Prop1 = myNewDic;` creates an not referenced object on the heap that have to be garbage collected. The second case just creates a local object and copies the values to the already creaded instance variable. Therefore there is no need do garbage collect anything.

**Proof:**

If you initilize `myNewDic` outside the for loop, the line `customObjects[indx].Prop1 = myNewDic;` is faster because you are using always the same object.

Comment: In both cases in the OP's code, the new dictionary is created - in both cases, one dictionary has to be collected. Sure, you're dealing with a different dictionary, which can have a performance effect (you need to compact the heap if you're collecting something on the bottom), but the OP didn't demonstrate any of that. The real issue is creating the dictionary in the first place anyway :)

Comment: @Luaan: _in both cases, one dictionary has to be collected_. That is not correct - in case of the foreach loop, the dictionary will be created in local scope (within the delegate of the `Parallel.For` loop) so the allocated memory can be dellocated directly without gc.

Comment: Not in C#, not in .NET. The dictionary is still allocated on the heap, and it will still only ever be collected by the GC. `Dictionary` is a reference type, it simply cannot exist on the stack in valid code. It will most likely be on a different heap, though - as I describe in my answer.

Comment: @Luaan: OK. Thanks for the detailed clarification in you answer.

Comment: @Luaan "Dictionary is a reference type, it simply cannot exist on the stack in valid code": Do not be too sure about it -- Eric Lippert insists that "heap" is an implementation detail. If the compiler can prove (which it could here) that the reference doesn't leave scope, it is free to actually allocate the object proper on the stack (much like `alloca` in BSD and GNU).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider We're talking about actual existing implementations of .NET here. Of course it's technically possible to do so, and there's plenty of implementations that do exactly that (e.g. GraalVM on JVM), and it's not big deal in non-managed code either.

Comment: @Luaan "Simply cannot exist" is not in itself a statement about actual existing implementations ;-), and is a flat contradiction to "Of course it's technically possible".

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Of course it isn't. The same way, I could take your "Eric Lipper insists that "heap" is an implementation detail" and say that it simply isn't true, because the CLI specification clearly contains heaps as part of the specification. Sure, they have nothing to do with what we're discussing here (they're part of the metadata specification), but you didn't say you meant "managed memory heaps used for allocation and participating in GC compaction and collection and... [continued for another 100 pages of text]" There's a reason we don't always include all the context :)

Comment: @Luaan Sorry: Everything I said is exactly true. No 100 pages required. What you said, by contrast was evidently self-contradicting.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Well, have fun in your exactly true world ;)